# oracle query complex

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_1(
    ID  NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
    PERSON VARCHAR2(30),
    DATETIMES  VARCHAR2(21),
    primary key(ID)  
);    

ID       PERSON         DATETIMES
    1       PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:29
    2       PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:29
    3       PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:29
    4       PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:29
    5       PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:29
    6       PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:29
    7       PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:29
    8       PERSON-3    20160114-03:01:29
    9       PERSON-4    20160114-03:01:29
    10      PERSON-4    20160114-03:01:29
    ---------------------------------------
    11      PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:56
    12      PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:56
    13      PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:56
    ---------------------------------------
    14      PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:45
    15      PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:45
    16      PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:45
    17      PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:45
    18      PERSON-3    20160114-03:01:45
    19      PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:45
    20      PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:45
```

FIRST TAKE THE COUNT(*) OF ABOVE TABLE group by DATETIME order by count

```
count(*)    DATETIME
---------   ------------
10          20160114-03:01:29
7           20160114-03:01:45
3           20160114-03:01:56
```

according to the squence from the datetimes in the above table .I need the table below

```
count(*)    PERSON          DATETIMES
---------   ------------    -----------------
5           PERSON-1        20160114-03:01:29
2           PERSON-2        20160114-03:01:29
2           PERSON-4        20160114-03:01:29
1           PERSON-3        20160114-03:01:29

count(*)    PERSON          DATETIMES
---------   ------------    -----------------
4           PERSON-2        20160114-03:01:45
2           PERSON-1        20160114-03:01:45
1           PERSON-3        20160114-03:01:45

count(*)    PERSON          DATETIMES
---------   ------------    -----------------
2           PERSON-1        20160114-03:01:56
1           PERSON-2        20160114-03:01:56
```

need this table: after group by person,datetimes

```
inside group,
    order by count(*) 
but group wise 
    order by DATETIMES
```

I tried but I cant get this table....

Comment: Why do you store date-times as VARCHAR2?

Comment: Can u be more clear? What you require is the output like you have mentioned above is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This.

```
        select COUNT(*) Count ,PERSON,datetimes from #TableName
        group by PERSON,datetimes
        order by datetimes asc , Count desc
```

> Output :

[image]

Check Demo [here](http://rextester.com/QKZDR24248) .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you want this `select`

```
SELECT COUNT(*), PERSON, DATETIME FROM table_name GROUP BY PERSON, DATETIME ORDER BY DATETIME
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Oracle analytical functions for same. They have ability to `count` with in specified group without using `group by` statement

Here is working version for you.

```
select distinct 
 count(*) over(partition by datetimes,person ) count,
 count(*) over(partition by datetimes ) group_count,
 person,
 datetimes 
from TEST_1 order by 2 desc,1 desc



COUNT   GROUP_COUNT PERSON  DATETIMES
---------------------------------------------
5       10          PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:29
2       10          PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:29
2       10          PERSON-4    20160114-03:01:29
1       10          PERSON-3    20160114-03:01:29
4       7           PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:45
2       7           PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:45
1       7           PERSON-3    20160114-03:01:45
2       3           PERSON-1    20160114-03:01:56
1       3           PERSON-2    20160114-03:01:56
```

Coulmn 2 is extra, but its needed for order by clause. You can write a wrapper over this query if you want to eliminate that column from result.

- Oder by 2 (group count) ensures `DATETIMES` is sorted based on group count.
- Order by 1 (count) ensures with in each group, `persons` are sorted based on their `count` with in `datetimes`

Here is link if want to try yourself http://rextester.com/YQQ34095

Comment: Why should u go for analytical functions when the same can be achieved by simply using a group by clause? Please check the above posts if you want to understand what i mean.

Only if he has asked for the group count then you could have mentioned the analytical functions. No where has he asked for a group count.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar  AFAIK, the order in which data was requested can not be achieved by simple group by statement. If you could show us otherwise, it will be something new to learn.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar Order of `DATETIME` is determined by the descending order of `count` total rows with in each `datetime` group. Further with in each `datetime` group, details of person is necessary in the descending order of `count` per `person` in the same `datetime` group

Comment: Can u please execute this query with the data provided by the user and compare the output?

SELECT COUNT(*), PERSON, DATESTIMES FROM person GROUP BY PERSON, DATESTIMES ORDER BY DATESTIMES,Count(*) desc

Comment: please add * inside the count() before u execute it.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar But this will order results based on `datetime` which is different from stated requirement. Requirement is to "FIRST TAKE THE COUNT(*) OF ABOVE TABLE group by DATETIME order by count. according to the squence from the datetimes in the above table .I need the table below"

Comment: Have u tried executing that code and cross checked with the output op desired??

Comment: @VimalBhaskar, Yes and it works only for this data. Not if dataset is different. (ex: if datetime `20160114-03:01:45` has 15 records). thats why I've suggested analytical functions, which meets requirements specified in question.

Comment: Not clear with the above statement. Different dataset would also work out. Anyways your logic would also workout so does others, Based on the user output the others have framed a simple query. Also the user has not yet provided a clear picture of the problem. Lets just wait till then.